# Possibility to add spacing between stacks of a stacked column in amCharts 5

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts4, amcharts5

I'm working on upgrading from amCharts 4 to amCharts 5. Previously in amCharts 4 it was easy to add a space between the individual stacks of a stacked column via template adapters like below

```js
columnSeries.columns.template.column.adapter.add('paddingTop', () => 1);
columnSeries.columns.template.column.adapter.add('paddingBottom', () => 1);
```

Example of spacing between column stacks in amCharts 4:
[image: working sample in amCharts 4]

I could not find a solution the get the same behavior after upgrading to amCharts 5.

Since there is no `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` anymore on the template I tried using the `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` property on `am5xy.ColumnSeries` itself. Using a `paddingTop` results in shifting the whole stacked column downward while `paddingBottom` does not do anything. I've expected the paddings to work the same as the ones on the template itself in amCharts 4.

amCharts 5 stacked column series without padding applied:
[image: amCharts 5 without padding]

same amCharts 5 stacked column series with a padding of 100px applied:
[image: amCharts 5 with padding]

I've also tried adding adapters for `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` and also using `marginTop`/`marginBotton` but still no effect.

Is there any other option to add a space between the columns?